# Was the main protagonist Shin in the manga Kingdom a real historical figure?

Tags: kingdom

As the question suggests, I wanted to ask if there really was some commoner like Shin in *Kingdom* who became one of the greatest generals of Qin Dynasty in reality or according to the Warring States-era history?

Answer (score 4):

Yes he was. He was based off Li Xin.

Here is a great resource describing many of the similarities / differences: [link](https://magaxking.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/ri-shinli-xin/)

Answer (score 2):

It is true that Shin is based on a real-life historical figure by the name of Li Xin. But he wasn't a commoner. In fact, he was actually the son of the governor of the Nanjun Commandery.

And about him being one of the greatest Qin generals, he certainly was a prominent general. He was one of the generals who played a very crucial role in the unification of China.